# how to fetch data from nested child array of json in jquery datatable using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, datatable

i get datatable when i am fetch data from root object of this json but when i try to fetch data of child array it get in string format and i want it table format.
Json Code

```
  [
   {
       "error": false,
       "data": [
           {
               "id": 1,
               "Name": "Shivraj Singh",
               "Mobile": "9787475412",
               "VehichleNo": "RJ 19 SV 4514",
           },
           {
               "id": 4,
               "Name": "Vinayak",
               "Mobile": "9782421454",
               "VehichleNo": "asdas",
           },
       ]
   }
]
```

Code Behind

```
 table = $("#contact").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                //type: "POST",
                url: "/api/Contact",
                dataSrc: "",
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "data[0].Name",

                },
                {
                    data: "data[0].Mobile",
                },
                {
                    data: "data[0].VehichleNo",
                },

            ],
        });
```

by this got data not in correct format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the sample JSON output data provided, below code should work.
Here in `"aaData"`, simply pass the result that you are getting from the api call.

```
$.ajax({
    'url': "/api/Contact",
    'method': "POST",
    'contentType': 'application/json'
}).done( function(response) {
    $('#contact').dataTable( {
        "aaData": response[0].data,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "Name" },
            { "data": "Mobile" },
            { "data": "VehichleNo" }
        ]
    })
})
```

Comment: Above method gives me "no data in my datatable" but when i use same method for parent element of json like error and date then its work perfectly but want to fetch second array data in my table

Comment: Just put console.log(response.data) below the done method of ajax, you will get a fair idea about ajax response data and its format. If it gives you an array then in datatable simply use "aaData": response.data[0], This would give you data into the datatable.

Comment: Please amend the answer with the change which i suggest replace "aaData" : response.data by "aaData" : response[0].data